# WPF binding UserControl collection to ItemsControl. DataTemplate issue

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

http://www.filedropper.com/wpfapplication9
that link has a project in VS2013 with a sample issue.

my problem is, how to set DataTemplate to UserControl, in ItemsControl.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

my Collections is a

```
public IEnumerable<MyUC> Collection {get;}
```

my MyUC is a

```
public partial class MyUC : UserControl
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to show that collection im getting

```
MyUC.Content
```

insted

```
MyUC.Title
```

when i change ItemsSouce to ListBox, datatemplate starts working.
but i need to show collection without ListBox addons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to display the `Title` property value of your `UserControl`s from your collection. All that you have to do is to declare an appropriate `DataTemplate` for them in the `Resources` section:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="x:Type={YourPrefix:MyUC}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

To be honest though, you seem to be going about this in the wrong way. In WPF, we generally *don't* put UI elements into collections, instead preferring to work with custom data classes that have `DataTempate`s to define what they should look like. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TitleTemplate" DataType="x:Type={YourPrefix:MyDataClass}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate" DataType="x:Type={YourPrefix:MyDataClass}">
    <YourControlPrefix:MyUC />
</DataTemplate>
```

You'd then use the `TitleTemplate` when you want to see just the `Title` property values and the `ControlTemplate` when you want to see the whole `UserControl`.

Comment: i was trying to declare DataTemplate in Resource, but its not working either. i need have collection of UC, because im writing classes to maintance docking system.

Comment: *i need have collection of UC*... no you don't... you just don't understand how to use WPF properly yet. See the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information on how to use it correctly. Also, just think about it... why do you think that a `DataTemplate` is called a `DataTemplate` and not a `UserControlTemplate`?

Comment: so, are you trying to say me.
that the window docking system, should keep collection of UC ?
so then how could i swap user's UC on Window, without collection of UC ?

Comment: Not at all. I'm saying exactly what I said: *In WPF, we generally don't put UI elements into collections, instead preferring to work with [collections of] custom data classes that have `DataTempate`s to define what they should look like*.